Remove all commas inside a number
LaTeX has a package, siunitx that provides a command, \num{123.45}.
I want to remove all commas inside the \num{} command only.
The difficulty here is that I want to:

Check that I'm inside \num{} (I thought of a positive lookbehind at the start).
Check for \d+,, without matching the \d+. I want something like a positive lookbehind to check there's numbers before the comma, which is not matched, then a comma that is matched. The difficulty is that this should be repeated as many times as it's needed (I was thinking of grouping it and +ing it).
The last part of the expression should be a positive lookahead to check for the final digits and the closing }.

I came up with this:
(?<=\\num\{[\d.]+),(?=[\d,.]+\}).
However, it only works for the first comma. If I try to add a + to the group of digits and comma, the expression breaks down. So this is where I am:



original
target
working?




123,456.78
No change
✅


\num{123,456.78}
\num{123456.78}
✅


\num{123,456,789.01}
\num{123456789.01}
❌



Any ideas on how to come up with a single RegExp to do it? I have a gut feeling it may not be possible at all, but there may be some obscure construct I haven't thought of...

Your original regex does not match a comma with [\d.] pattern inside the lookbehind. If you add a comma there, it will work.
However, a more generic pattern can turn out more future-proof:
(?<=\\num\{[^{}]*),(?=[^{}]*\})

See the regex demo.
Now, it matches

(?<=\\num\{[^{}]*) - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with \nun{ and then any zero or more chars other than { and }
, - a comma
(?=[^{}]*\})  - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than { and } and then a }.

